# Faster Iterative Calculation

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a script that performs an iterative calculation to find values based on a gross percentage of project cost.

This is what I have so far:

```
//<!-- FEE, BOND, & INSURANCE CALCULATOR --!>
function feeBondInsCalculator (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pretty Sum Form");
  sheet.activate();
  // Get all variables from named ranges
  var bondValue = ss.getRangeByName("bondValue");
  var bondCalc = ss.getRangeByName("bondCalc");
  var insValue = ss.getRangeByName("insValue");
  var insCalc = ss.getRangeByName("insCalc");
  var feeValue = ss.getRangeByName("feeValue");
  var feeCalc = ss.getRangeByName("feeCalc");
  var interCount = ss.getRangeByName("interCount")

  // Interative calculation to paste calculated values into the body of the spreadsheet
    for (var i = 0; i<11; i++){
      feeCalc.copyTo(ss.getRangeByName("feeValue"), {contentsOnly: true});
      bondCalc.copyTo(ss.getRangeByName("bondValue"), {contentsOnly: true});
      insCalc.copyTo(ss.getRangeByName("insValue"), {contentsOnly: true});
      interCount.setValue(i)
    } 
  }
```

I used range names so that users can add/delete rows and columns and not have to reset the code. When executed, the code works fine, but takes about two seconds per iteration. Is there a more efficient way to make this work?

Comment: Why do you need the `copyTo()` lines in the `for` loop?  The only line in the `for` loop that has dynamic information is `interCount.setValue(i)`.  Aren't the `copyTo()` lines just doing the same thing over and over again?  If so, you only need to do that once.

Comment: This could be a question for [codereview.se]. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/91556)

Comment: @SandyGood I need these values in the copyTo() because they are a part of the total sum of project cost and based on a percentage of project cost. During the first 4 or 5 iterations, each time ranges are copied and pasted, the overall project cost changes and therefore the values of each range is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using copy, you might try referencing your ranges directly in a formula like:

```
=arrayformula(if(bondValue <>"",bondValue,""))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Each range is just one cell, and I am not really working with arrays. I am more trying to create an iterative (circular) calculation.